# How to validate two email Id separated by ; using jquery/ javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

```
<div class="fluid field">
    <label>e-mail Ids:</label>
    <textarea rows="1" style="height:100px" id="mailids" value="<%- mailids %>"></textarea>
 </div>
```

> below is my JS code which i tried

```
'change #mailids': function (e) {
        var strVale = $(e.target).val();
        if (strVale.substring(strVale.length - 1) == ";") {
            strvalue = strVale.substring(0, strVale.length - 1);
        }
        var arr = strVale.split(';');
        var isValid = true;
        var self = this;

        arr.forEach(function (item) {
            var x = item;
            var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
            var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
                isValid = false;
            }
        });
      }
```

I need to validated the two email id separated by **`;`(semi colon)**  if its not valid email it should show error message

below input also accepts as valid

[image]

Comment: Have you tried regex?

Comment: What is the issue with your current code? How exactly does it fail?

Comment: using regex i can validated only one email after validating i need to separate it by ;

Comment: @ChrisG the issue is even if i give `colon (-)` also it will accept as valid email id other than `;` it should not accept anything

Comment: Why do you have value="" on the textarea? It should be `<textarea rows="1" style="height:100px" id="mailids"><%- mailids %></textarea>`

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, your issue *isn't* `How to validate two email Id separated by ; using jquery/ javascript`, but your issue is `How to validate email`?

Comment: @ChrisG No not to validate email if user gives multiple email it should be separated by ;

Comment: @mplungjan that is to for another purpose

Comment: Please add examples of input that fail your test.

Comment: @ChrisG see the image which i updated in the question

Comment: If you use a suitable regex for the address check, that input will fail because it is treated as a single address and thus won't pass the regex check.

Comment: Your issue is almost impossible. Instead have one email per field. If they need more, then have them add a field.

Answer (score 0):

Split the email is based on the semicolon. And for each email id, use a regular expression to validate email.

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

For regular expression based validation. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/3048967) answer.

Comment: @ScrapCode from this answer i can't pass two email id

Comment: @chethu, for each email id (that you got after splitting), use the above function to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Just split email id's by comma or semicolon after that validate them

this will help you

```
 var x = getEmails();
var emails = x.split(",");
emails.forEach(function (email) {
  validate(email.trim());
});
```